# Asymptotic (divergent) behavior of modified alternating harmonic series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, divergent-series, harmonic-numbers

I was fiddling around with some numerical sums in Mathematica, and I noticed that the partial sums of the following series seemed to follow a nice pattern:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{10^k}\left( \frac{1}{n} \right)^{p(n)} \approx \frac{5}{3} \cdot 10^{2k-1},$$

where $p(n) = 1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,\ldots$ is periodic with period 3 ([OEIS A131561](https://oeis.org/A131561)).

Phrased another way, it seems as though the sequence
$$
 a_k = \left( \frac{3}{5\cdot 10^{2k-1}} \right) \left( \sum_{n=1}^{10^k}\left( \frac{1}{n} \right)^{p(n)} \right)
$$
has limit $a_k \to 1$.

Is anyone familiar with results like these? Or perhaps even with results about asymptotic growth of divergent series in general? I was a bit surprised that the partial sums of this divergent series were so "nicely" behaved; I expected them to be rather chaotic.

Am I missing something? Is this kind of behavior a result of the particular way I've chosen my partial sums? Is there something more intricate going on here?

**EDIT:** I modified my sum in Mathematica a bit, and now I'm more convinced that there is something non-trivial going on. Based on experimental evidence, it seems as though I can drop the dependence on powers of 10 and the result still holds:
$$
\alpha_{j} = \left( \frac{3}{5} \cdot \frac{10}{j^2} \right) \left( \sum_{n=1}^{j}\left( \frac{1}{n} \right)^{p(n)} \right) \to 1,
$$
or
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{j}\left( \frac{1}{n} \right)^{p(n)} \approx \frac{5}{30} \cdot j^2
$$

Comment: You are essentially summing a harmonic-like series with a series whose general term has a linear growth. The whole question boils down to $H_n\approx\log(n)$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{N}n\approx\frac{N^2}{2}$, nothing more.

Comment: This is not quite as interesting as you'd hoped (as @JackD'Aurizio points out) but +1 for exploration and curiousity.

Comment: Ah. Oh well. Thanks for the info.